# How can I get HealthKit daily Steps count?

Tags: ios, healthkit

`HealthKit` I can't read the steps count from the device. I'm able to read data from my device but I'm getting **steps count = -0**.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code of what you are currently trying

Comment: Check the Answer [Try this code This will help u..](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39509779/4693326)